# Is it possible to custom custom, hard-coded legend

Tags: highcharts

I have a series which contain various data columns, each represented as columns in a gantt chart. There are many columns represented by 5 different colors that I would like to show up on the a legend.

```
legendItems = [ {name: "type1", color1: "#0082c8"},
                {name: "type2", color1: "#f58231"},
                {name: "type3", color1: "#911eb4"},
                {name: "type4", color1: "#911eb4"},
                {name: "type5", color1: "#911eb4"} 
               ]
```

Is it possible to create a legend with the 5 colors and what they represent based on `legendItems`, without having to depend on the number of series?

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom legend buttons, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pvhud6zb/

Also Highcharts provide `linkedTo` option for series, which allow you to combine more than one series in one legend item:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [2,2,2]
  },{
    data: [1,2,3],
    id: 'secondSeries'
  },{
    data: [3,2,1],
    linkedTo: 'secondSeries'
  }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pfraLzgs/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo

Comment: The custom legend button works for me as a short term solution, thank you!